# Register Page - Already Exit Email - How can I give a good message to user without breaking privacy?

Tags: website-design, privacy

We have clearly mentioned that "we don't give personal data including email address to any third party" in our privacy policy.

So when a user try to create a account using already exit email address, I can't give a error like "Email is already registered" because it is clearly break own our privacy policy.

So what can be the process / good message to handle this situation?

Comment: Your policy states that "You don't share email addresses with any third party" not that you can't store it in your own application.

Comment: @Shaz Similar one https://medium.com/@intideceukelaire/porn-sites-have-a-privacy-problem-a6e78645450b

Answer (score 1):

Why not give an error message that is less explicit about the problem?

For example, when the users enters with an existing email they could get a message like this.

> Login has failed. This may be due to an incorrect email, password or the account is already registered.

However, when I first read the question I failed to understand why it is a breach of their privacy anyway. Just because the system knows they have an account doesn't mean you give any info to third parties does it?

Comment: Similar one how it harmful https://medium.com/@intideceukelaire/porn-sites-have-a-privacy-problem-a6e78645450b

Comment: What an exciting job you must have...